# Is there any way to stop the lag in this Gif opener?

Tags: python, performance, tkinter

Recently, I made this gif opener using tkinter:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import time
import threading

def getfile():
     file = fd.askopenfilename()
     window = tk.Toplevel()
     def run_gif():
          i = 0
          while True:
               try:
                    photo = tk.PhotoImage(file = file,format="gif -index" +' '+ str(i))
                    gif = tk.Label(window, image=photo)
                    gif.grid(row=0,column=0)
                    i += 1
                    time.sleep(0.0001)
               except:
                    i = 0
     gif_thread=threading.Thread(target=run_gif)
     gif_thread.start()
     window.mainloop()
          
          
def display():
     root = tk.Tk()
     root.title(".gif opener")
     root.geometry('50x100')
     root.configure(bg = "lightgreen")
     label = tk.Label(root, text = ".gif opener")
     label.pack()
     button = tk.Button(root, text = "File", command = getfile)
     button.place(x = "50", y= "50")
     root.mainloop()

display()
```

However, every time I open a gif, the animation is really laggy.

Is there any way to make the gifs flow smoother? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why is there a `sleep()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may be similar to this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904093/gif-animation-in-tkinter-with-pill-flickering-on-every-other-frame

I tried your code on gif which has a 2nd disposal method.
Works, but loops over frames too quickly. GIFs with the 1st disposal method fail.

Also pay attention to the frame delay/frame rate. Different GIFs can have different values.
You can use third party libraries like [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) to get file information.

```py
from PIL import Image

f = Image.open("tenor.gif")
print(f.info) # duration in ms
print(f.disposal_method)
print(f.n_frames) # number of frames
```

Output example:

```
{'version': b'GIF89a', 'background': 140, 'transparency': 140, 'duration': 160, 'extension': (b'NETSCAPE2.0', 795), 'loop': 0}
2
12
```

You can use some custom label classes.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43770948/8349697

Consider using the [PyQt5](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/) library. I tried some test gifs with QtWidgets, and it works much better than tkinter. PyQt can display animated gifs using QMovie.